# Is there a way in SQL to determine if certain days are in the same week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table 'Schedule' in my database:

```
**Schedule**
PK Weekday (ie., November 11, 2012)
PK Punch-In (ie., 1:00 PM)
PK Punch-Out (ie., 9:00 PM)
```

I am tasked with totaling the number of hours worked per week.

For my example Sunday is Day 1 of the week and Saturday is Day 7.

My question is how do I determine which days are in a "week." Is there an SQL command for this? In other words, how do I determine if November 10 is the same week as November 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WEEK()` function, which returns week number so `WHERE WEEK(date1) = WEEK(date2)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Week function should return week number, if this is what you want?